# C++ Infix to Postfix works for some inputs but not for others?

Tags: c++

I asked a question last night regarding a computer science class program in which I must convert infix to postfix notation and evaluate. I was able to debug it and get it working (somewhat), however, I am still getting weird outputs for some expressions.

It works for the first iteration with basic inputs like 7+7, 3+2, etc... however, once you add parentheses, or other expressions, it goes out of wack and I cannot figure out why.

The code is below along with the text file/output I am getting.

Header file:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////Includes/////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
template <typename Object>
class Stack
{
private:
    class stackListNode
        {
        public:
            Object data;
            stackListNode *next;
        private:
            //Nothing to declare-->placeholder since class 
            //sets data members to private initially
        };

    stackListNode *top;

public:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Constructor Function//////////////////////////
    Stack() {top = NULL;}

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Rest of functions defined inline for simplicity

        void push(char token)   // Push token onto the stack and create new node for top of stack
            {
                stackListNode *newNode = new stackListNode;
                newNode->data = token;
                newNode->next = top;
                top = newNode;
            }

        char pop()
            {
                if(empty())
                {
                    cout << "Stack is empty!\n" << endl;
                    return NULL;                
                }

                stackListNode *temp = top;
                top = temp->next;
                return temp->data;
            }

        char peek()
            {
                if(empty())
                {
                    cout << "Stack is empty!\n" << endl;
                    //exit(1);
                    return NULL;                
                }
                return top->data;
            }

        int empty()
            {
                return top == NULL;
            }
};

#endif
```

Driver:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////Includes/////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Stack.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;

int precendence(char stack_beginning); //overloaded for character sitting at the front of the stack
void InFixToPostfix(ifstream& in_file);
//double EvaluatePostfix(double first_operand, double second_operand, char*myArray);

int main()
{
////VARS/////////////////////////////////////////////

    string absolutePath;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please type in the name of the file you would to open \n";
    cin >> absolutePath;

    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(absolutePath.c_str());
    if(!in_file)
    {
        cout << "failed to open input file\n" ;
        return 1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        InFixToPostfix(in_file); //kicks off program
    }

}

void InFixToPostfix(ifstream& in_file)
{
    string infix;
    int right_parentheses = 0;
    int left_parentheses = 0;

    while(getline(in_file, infix))
    {
        char myArray[infix.length()];
        strcpy(myArray, infix.c_str());


        ////////Declares a STRING Stack////////////////////////////////
        Stack<char> stack_string;
        ////////Declares an Int Stack/////////////////////////////////
        Stack<double> stack_int;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int j = 0;
        char *postfix = new char[infix.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(myArray); i++)
        {
            int number = myArray[i] - '0';
            if(number > 0)
            {
                postfix[j] = myArray[i];
                j++;
                //outputs the number b/c it is an operand
            }
            else if(myArray[i] == ')')
            {
                while(stack_string.peek() != '(')
                {
                    cout << stack_string.peek() << " ";
                    stack_string.pop(); //pops to the peek
                }
            stack_string.pop(); // if there is a ), pops to the peek
            }
            else if(myArray[i] == '+' || myArray[i] == '-' || myArray[i] == '/' || myArray[i] == '*' || myArray[i] == '(')
            {
                if(!stack_string.empty())
                    {
                        char stack_beginning = stack_string.peek();
                        int stack_top = precendence(stack_beginning);
                        //int stack_top = precendence(stack_string.peek());
                        int operatorHierarchy = precendence(myArray[i]);
                        //must be declared here because i will have been interated through array
                        while(operatorHierarchy >= stack_top)
                        {
                            stack_string.pop();
                            postfix[j] = myArray[i];
                            j++;
                            stack_top = precendence(stack_beginning);
                            operatorHierarchy = precendence(myArray[i]);
                        }
                    }
                stack_string.push(myArray[i]);
            }
        }
        while(!stack_string.empty())
        {
           char c = (char)stack_string.pop();
           postfix[j] = c;
           j++;

        }

        //////////Evaluate Section/////////////////////////////
        cout << postfix <<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            //cout<<myArray[i]<<endl;
            cout << postfix[i] <<endl;
            int number = postfix[i] - '0';
            if(number > 0) //this is a number
            {
                stack_int.push(number);
                cout << stack_int.peek();
            }
            else if(postfix[i] == '*' || postfix[i] == '+' || postfix[i] == '-' || postfix[i] == '/')
            {
                double first_operand;
                first_operand = stack_int.peek(); //fetches first operand on the stack_int
                stack_int.pop();
                //////////////////
                double second_operand;
                second_operand = stack_int.peek();
                stack_int.pop();
                //////////////////
                if(postfix[i] == '+')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand + first_operand);
                }
                else if(postfix[i] == '-')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand - first_operand);
                }
                else if(postfix[i] == '*')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand * first_operand);
                }
                else if(postfix[i] == '/')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand / first_operand);
                }
            }
        }
    cout << (double)stack_int.pop() << endl;
    }
}

int precendence(char stack_beginning)
{
    int precendence;
    if(stack_beginning == '(')
    {
        precendence = 3;
        return precendence;
    }
    else if(stack_beginning == '*' || stack_beginning == '/')
    {
        precendence = 2;
        return precendence;
    }
    //by making it 2, the precendence is dubbed less than +/-
    else if(stack_beginning == '+' || stack_beginning == '-')
    {
        precendence = 1;
        return precendence;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}    //by making it 1, the precendence is dubbed greater than */"/"
```

Text File:

```
9+5
(4+2)
(3+8)/2
```

Output:

```
Please type in the name of the file you would to open 
f.txt
95+
9
    5
+
14
+ 42
4
2
2
+ 382/
3
8
2
/
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some issues I have identified:

**C-Style strings or std::string, not both**
You are using `strcpy` with `std::string::c_str()`.
Stick with the `std::string`.
You can access individual characters by treating as an array, string[5] returns the 6th character.

**Char stack differs from a string stack**
Your comments say a stack of strings, but yet you declare `Stack<char>` which is a stack of characters, not a string.
Similarly, Stack is not a stack of integers.
You are dynamically allocating a character of arrays, when you should stick with a variable of `std::string`.

**Use library functions.**
See `isdigit` and `toupper` and `tolower`.

**Use a debugger**
Now is a good time to use a debugger.  Single step through your program and look at variables.

**Use print statements**
If you refuse to use a debugger, place "print" statements in your code with the line numbers to get a snapshot of your program's behavior.